# Host a website with a domain so others can access it?

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, wamp

I'm currently hosting WordPress on localhost on WAMP (Windows 10). The site works fine, but I don't know how to make it so that I set a .com domain I already own and leave my computer on so anyone in the world can access it. Sorry if this was asked before and is a basic question; I didn't see it already asked from the search bar. Also, my IP address is dynamic, so I don't know how that'd work either.

Comment: Someone probably has written a whole book with the answer to your question. There are a lot of ins and outs and whatifs to consider but that makes the question far too broad to answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to purchase hosting Daniel. I suggest krystal.co.uk as you can try them for £1, Then just change your nameservers on the domain account!
This would be a lot easier and cheaper for you in the longrun than hosting it yourself on your own pc!

Comment: *You need to purchase hosting...* That is not true. I do agree that for newbies, it is likely better to host, however, that does not negate the necessity to know what you are doing. In the OPs case, a simple domain name registration with DDNS is all he needs to start. GoDaddy will do fine. I would also suggest that the OP become very familiar with their firewall or get a good one fast! Remember that hosts offer no firewall. A simple and effective consumer grade router will have a decent enough firewall. It is possible to get more advanced features for just a few dollars more. Cheers!!